# Cannot copy data from Snowflake into Azure Blob

Tags: azure-data-factory, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, azure-blob-storage, azure-container-service

I am trying to copy data from Snowflake into an Azure Blob using Azure Data Factory.

The role I am using has select permissions on the table, and I have no issues querying the data using the Snowflake console.

I am also able to copy into the targeted blob from other sources (in Azure) using the same SAS token.

This is the query I have, generated by Azure Data Factory, (with specifics omitted)

```
COPY INTO 'azure://****.blob.core.windows.net/snowflake-stage/********-****-****-****-************/SnowflakeExportCopyCommand/'
FROM (select * from MYSCHEMA.MYTABLE)
CREDENTIALS = (AZURE_SAS_TOKEN = '****')
FILE_FORMAT = (type = CSV COMPRESSION = GZIP RECORD_DELIMITER = '
' FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY = '"' ESCAPE = '\\' NULL_IF = '')
HEADER = TRUE
SINGLE = FALSE
OVERWRITE = TRUE
MAX_FILE_SIZE  = 268435456
```

And this is the error I am getting:

> ErrorCode=UserErrorOdbcOperationFailed,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=ERROR
> [42501] Failed to access remote file: access denied.
>
> Please check your credentials,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Runtime.GenericOdbcConnectors,''Type=System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException,Message=ERROR
> [42501] Failed to access remote file: access denied. Please check your
> credentials,Source=Snowflake,'

Are there more Snowflake permissions that I need in order to do this kind of copy? Or is this perhaps an issue with the write-permissions to the Azure container?

Comment: Is snowflake-stage within your URL a stage name or the container name?

Comment: Are you sure that token you are using has write access to the container?

Comment: @AbhiReddy it is the container name.

Comment: @MikeWalton yes.

This does appear to be related to the access to the container and not an issue on the Snowflake side though. I've marked the "solution" in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The "solution" for this indicates a likely bug for the permissions on the blob itself.

Switching the container permissions to public, then back to private again fixes the issue.