# Snowflake error when reading from Azure stage using SAS token

Tags: azure-blob-storage, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, azure-sas

Snowflake stage for Azure blob giving error when we try to copy the file into snowflake table

Error:Failed to access remote file: access denied. Please check your credentials

We are able to list the files but unable to copy the files.

This issue occured when we are reading this file from third party source system (Azure Blob).
We are able to repo the same issue in our environment when we remove read access while generating the SAS token but third party source team generating with read access but still showing error.

Third party team whitelisted snowflake subnet ranges to avoid the misuse of SAS token.

Regards,
Srinivas

Answer (score 1):

> Error:Failed to access remote file: access denied. Please check your
> credentials

It looks like SAS token permissions are not enough. Try to add full permissions and try again:

[image]

And you can try this answer(maybe helpful):

[Cannot copy data from Snowflake into Azure Blob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65345818/cannot-copy-data-from-snowflake-into-azure-blob)